# How to get the contents of an iframe?

Tags: php, javascript, html

How do i extract all the text from an iframe ?

Is there any way to do this ?

Comment: Is this iframe part of your domain because if it isn't you would be violating the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)?

Comment: You've tagged this PHP and JavaScript. Are you talking about doing this in the browser with JS or are you parsing a document with PHP, finding an iframe in it, then parsing the referenced document?

Comment: Guys,I'm just interested in knowing how to do and NOT To DO IT !!

Comment: Yeah, I found it can be a bit harsh around here when the questions are not clear/complete. It is a learning process ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clientside Same domain:

```
var doc;
if (document.getElementById(iframeId).contentDocument) { // newer browsers
  doc = document.getElementById(iframeId).contentDocument;
}
else if (document.getElementById(iframeId).contentWindow) { // older IE
  doc = document.getElementById(iframeId).contentWindow.document
}
if (doc) { alert(doc.body.innerHTML) }
```

If not, you need an HTA for windows or a proxy on the server