# How to get content of iframe as a string using php?

Tags: php, iframe

I have a page which is only have strings, something like that:

```
Hi Hello World
```

when I do this:

```
<?php
$var="<iframe  src='hi.php'></iframe>";
echo $var;
?>
```

it worked perfectly

but when I want to do operations on the content strings it won't work:

```
<?php
$var="<iframe  src='hi.php'></iframe>";
$var2 =`echo $var | awk ' { print $1 } '`;
?>
```

what should I do?

NOTE:
I don't want it with js like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410672/how-to-get-the-contents-of-an-iframe), I want it with php.

Comment: Consider that you're stuffing some HTML directly into a command line. Think of how that HTML is going to appear to the shell... And consider that PHP has perfectly good html manipulation libraries available. There is absolutely **ZERO** reason to fire some html into a command line command just to run it through awk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) PHP function works well.

```
<?php
$var = file_get_contents("hi.php");
echo $var;
?>
```

Comment: This is a better way than my answer actually.

Comment: @user78050, yes but just make sure to specify the entire URL e.g. file_get_contents("http://www.example.com/hi.php");

Comment: thanks it worked perfectly, I'll accept the answer as soon as I can

Answer (score 1):

Creating an iframe in a string like that won't load the file in src. Your betting off using CURL to load the other page.

```
$ch = curl_init();  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'hi.php');  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  

$contents = curl_exec($ch);  
curl_close($ch);
```